# Setting opacity for everything except border of divs

Tags: html, css, border, opacity

Right I want to have some divs, where everything inside them has a certain opacity, yet the border of the div is normal. Now I know when you set an opacity to a div, it applies it to everything.

So. I have tried splitting them into two divs like this:

```
<div id="border">
<div class="content">
hello
</div>
</div>
```

with

```
#border{
border: 1px solid #000;
}

.content{
opacity:0.1;
}
```

This gives the opacity I want, but it doesnt have the right height or width. I dont want to define a width in #border (i have random sizes) It seems to make it full screen width and 0px high.

Alternatively, does anyone have any alternative methods?

Thanks

Comment: What is your problem? You start out with opcaity issues then end with height and width? Can you make an example on www.jsfiddle.net?

Comment: sorry, i'll edit it so it makes sense! and ill get that jsfiddle in a sec

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, use:

```
#border{ display: inline-block; }
```

also remove any declaration of `width` or `height` for `#border` or set them to `auto`

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/USPgZ/1/)

Answer (score 0):

You do not have to use two different divs! Just use this css syntax:

```
.parent {
 border:1px solid black;
}
.parent .child {
 opacity:0.5;
}
```

and if you do not want to give every child element a class you can use the * selector:

```
.parent * {
 opacity:0.5;
}
```